# print line with 4 words using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed

I'm using Bash in Ubuntu 20.04.

I have file:

```
Hello hi 123
if a equals b
you
one abc two three four
dany uri four 123
```

I need to found with `sed` only- the lines with only 4 words .
This is the code I wrote and it does not work, it prints exactly the file.

```
sed "/[a-Z0-9+]{4}/g" F1
```

Comment: Why `sed` only when it would be much easier with `awk`?  Also, why is this tagged with [tag:bash]?  Also, what `sed` are you using that accepts the expression that you gave? It should give an error message.

Comment: Because that's what I've learned so far, and the question asks for it in sed only.

Comment: How do you define a word? Any cluster of non-space characters? Is `middle-man` one or two words? Text-processing questions are better with a minimal, complete example (input and expected output), it would be nice to see one here.

Comment: Are you on Windows or Unix ? If it's Unix then the first thing you should have learned is to enclose scripts in single quotes (`'...'`), not double (`"..."`). If it's Windows then the first thing you should have learned is to put scripts in a file and execute them with `sed -f ...` instead of on the command line to avoid Windows nightmarish quoting rules. Do you have GNU sed?

Answer (score 4):

This should really be solved with a tool that easily counts fields, like `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NF == 4' file
if a equals b
dany uri four 123
```

This uses `NF`, a special variable in `awk` that will hold the number of fields in the current record. By default, a record is a line, and a field will be any substring delimited by one or more blank characters (tabs or spaces), not counting empty fields at the start or end of the lines.  The above short `awk` program would output any line with exactly four fields.

---

With `sed`, you would need to match blank-delimited substrings.

Note that `sed` by default uses basic regular expression, and that the expression that you show uses `{4}`, which is an extended regular expression modifier.  The equivalent thing in a basic regular expression would be written `\{4\}`. You also use an invalid character range, `a-Z`, and the character class that you intend to use is better written as `[[:alnum:]]`, i.e. something matching any alphanumeric character (assuming that the inclusion of `+` is a typo).  The trailing `g` command (gets the data from the "hold space") seems misplaced.

The general idea I have here is to compress each word (run of one or more non-blank character) into a single `x` each, then to delete all blank characters (tabs or spaces).  If the resulting string is exactly `xxxx`, print the original line (otherwise delete the line and start the next cycle immediately).

```
sed -e h \
    -e 's/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/x/g' \
    -e 's/[^x]//g' \
    -e '/^xxxx$/!d' \
    -e g file
```

Here, the original line is first saved to the "hold space" with `h`, and then fetched again if it needs to be printed, with `g` at the end.  If the `d` command on the penultimate line is executed, the final `g` will never be considered.

Or, using extended regular expressions:

```
sed -E -e h \
    -e 's/[^[:blank:]]+/x/g' \
    -e 's/[^x]//g' \
    -e '/^xxxx$/!d' \
    -e g file
```

Testing:

```
$ sed -e h \
>     -e 's/[^[:blank:]]\{1,\}/x/g' \
>     -e 's/[^x]//g' \
>     -e '/^xxxx$/!d' \
>     -e g file
if a equals b
dany uri four 123
```

If you want your word-characters to be defined by the `[[:alnum:]]` class rather than by `[^[:blank:]]` (non-blanks), then change `[^[:blank:]]` to `[[:alnum:]]` in the expressions above.  The difference will be that strings such as `GNU/Linux` or `Unix-system` would counted as two words each rather than as a single word each.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU `sed`:

```
$ sed -E '/^\s*(\w+\s+){3}\w+\s*$/!d' infile
if a equals b
dany uri four 123
```

POSIXly; you could write:

```
sed '/^[[:space:]]*\([_[:alnum:]][_[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]][[:space:]]*\)\{3\}[_[:alnum:]][_[:alnum:]]*[[:space:]]*$/!d' infile
```

Answer (score 0):

With bash while read:

```
set -o noglob 

while IFS= read -r line
do
    set -- $line
    [ $# -eq 4 ] &&  echo "$line"
done < file
```

`$#`: number of arguments.

Comment: You're still missing the `set -o noglob` / `set -f`. You can't use `echo` for arbitrary data. In `bash`, you can use `read -a` (the equivalent of ksh/zsh/yash's `read -A`). See also: [Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/169716)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thank you, I will submit an edit.

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing `GNU sed` we create a regex that looks at optional leading space(s) followed by exactly 4 pairs of nonwhitespace(s)+whitespace(s) followed by thecend of pattern space.

```
$ sed -nE 'G;/^\s*(\S+\s+){4}$/P' F1
```

Alternatively,

```
sed -nE '
  s/\S+/&/4;T    # 3 or less chunks
  s//&/5;t       # 5 or more chunks 
  p              # exactly 4 chunks 
' F1

sed -E '
  s/\S+/&/5; td     # 5 or more chunks
  s//&/4; t         #  exactly 4 chunks
  :d;d              # 3 or less or 5 or more
' F1
```

Answer (score -1):

Obviously `awk` would be the better tool for this use case - but the OP specified `sed`.

Using GNU `sed`, many solutions are possible.  Here is one which uses the hold space:

```
$ cat -A file
Hello hi 123$
if a equals b$
you$
one abc two three four$
dany uri four 123$
   one two three four$
    five  six ^Iseven eight      $

$ sed -e 'h; s/^\s*//; s/\s*$//' -nre '/^\w+(\W+\w+){3}$/{g;p}' file
if a equals b
dany uri four 123
   one two three four
    five  six   seven eight      
$
```

This `sed` command can be simplified to:

```
$ sed -nr '/^\s*(\w+)(\W+\w+){3}\s*$/p' file
```

Here is another more portable version of the previous `sed` command which uses POSIX character classes and `-E` instead of `-r`:

```
$ sed -En '/^[[:blank:]]*[[:alnum:]]+([[:blank:]]+[[:alnum:]]+){3}[[:blank:]]*$/p' file
```